# Issue connecting with local database from sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting the following error while connecting to a local database (After I enter the
username and password
[image]
Following are the properties for this database that I am trying to

[image]

The services 1. OracleXETNSListener 2. OracleServiceXE
are running. I am not sure what could be causing this error and I am able to connect
to local DB with sqlplus command although with a different username and password
The listener.ora has the following entry:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = L05015765)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Also, I couldn't find any output for
netstat -aof | findstr :1521
netstat -aof | findstr :8080
netstat -aof | findstr :8082
which probably means nothing is running on 1521, and so the local connection that  I
want to make it on port 1521 as per the properties window in SQL developer.
I am not sure how to debug this further and what could be going wrong

Comment: If you've installed SQL Server, as your tag suggests, why are you trying to use **Oracle** SQL Developer to connect?

Comment: You are using Oracle SQL Developer to connect to sql server, but you have database type set to `Oracle` on your screenshot.

Comment: @Larnu, Isn't SQL developer a client software to connect to SQL server?

Comment: SQL Developer is a client application developed by Oracle Corporation primarily for connecting to Oracle databases; it can connect to other databases but, as previously mentioned, the setup you are using with "Database Type: Oracle" is trying to connect to an Oracle database and not a Microsoft SQL Server database. It you want to connect to a different RDBMS then change the "Database Type" option (or use a client application that is primarily for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server).

Comment: No, it's primarily to connect to Oracle, @dnaiel , as its name suggests. SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), as it's name suggests, is used for SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server is a Microsoft product; but perhaps that isn't what you meant by "SQL server" (with lowercase 's'). If not, remove that tag. As you also talk about OracleServiceXE etc. you do seem to be using Oracle - so should add that tag instead. Anyway... what happens if you change the connection hostname from `localhost` to `L05015765` to match the listener setting?

Comment: @GuidoG Oracle is the only option I see in SQL developer. I am running an Oracle server 11.2.0

Comment: I think I got confused with SQL and Oracle. It's an Oracle server that is running with the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora files

Comment: @AlexPoole, yeah, I can connect. Thanks a lot. But I am not sure what this L05015765 is. Does it refer to localhost or some other machine? you can post that as an answer I will select

Comment: @AlexPoole, I understood that SQL Server is a Microsoft product. But isn't this name confusing? I mean, SQL is a Structured query language that sounds quite generic. Does Microsoft own it?

Comment: @dnaiel - they don't own SQL (the standard or the name); and yes, the SQL Server name is sometimes confusing. People often refer to Microsoft SQL Server as just 'SQL', not even realising that is the language, which is even more confusing - there are often questions like 'how do I convert this SQL query to Oracle' which doesn't really make sense, as they want to convert between two flavours of SQL (and/or T-SQL to PL/SQL...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your listener configuration shows that is listening on port 1521 on `L05015765`. That is your PC's name, and in network terms will presumably resolve to your LAN IP address (e.g. 192.168.0.1).

Your SQL Developer connection is to port 1521 on `localhost`, which is a different network adapter, which will resolve to a different private, fixed , IP address, 127.0.0.1. (Although it may not actually work at all by default on Windows, I believe).

If you change your connection to use `L05015765` to match the listener configuration, you will be able to connect.